# Is $\log(x)|1-x/n|^n$ bounded?

Tags: elementary-functions

I have to find if the function $\log(x)|1-x/n|^n$ is bounded but I cannot. I have tried Bernoulli's inequality and a few others things.  Any hints please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x) = log(x)|1-x/n|^n$ is unbounded as a function of $x$.

If $x > e$, $f(x) > |1-x/n|^n$.

Further, if $x > n$, $f(x) > (\frac{x-n}{n})^n$ which clearly diverges as $x$ gets large.

On the lower end, as $x\rightarrow 0$, $log(x)\rightarrow -\infty$ while the absolute value term goes to 1.

Comment: I am sorry. I should have specified that we are looking for g(x) as log(x)|1−x/n|^n < g(x). Which means that I need to get rid of n and not x.